# Remove spaces and tokens from a string

Tags: java, string

I am giving string input as "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?"

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] split = s.split("[',',''','?','\\s','(',')',',',';']");
    for(String s1:split){
        if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            s1.trim();
        }
        System.out.println(s1);

    }
```

Expected Result:

[image: ExpectedResult:]

Actual Result:

[image: Actual Result]

Comment: Links also can break, just copy/paste the text into the question, even if it takes up screen space, it is more user friendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a `+` after your bracket for:

`String[] split = s.split("[',',''','?','\\s','(',')',',',';']+");`

Or simplify it to:

`String[] split = s.split("[,'?\\s();]+");`.

It will work how you expected since it will now match multiple characters in a row.

You will also no longer need to use `trim()` and just call:

```
for(String s1:split){
    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Comment: Matches 1 _or more_.

Answer (score 1):

`.trim()` removes whitespace. I.e. `"     "` becomes `""`. It is not able, however, to remove it from the list. `String.split()` doesn't know about your list.

The following will do what you want:

```
String[] split = s.split("<your regex>");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(split);

list.stream()  // convert to a stream for easy filtering
    .filter(s -> s.trim().equals(""))  // if s.trim().equals(""), remove it from the list/stream
    .forEach(System.out::println);  // print every remaining element
```